# Depends: python-httplib2 but it is not going to be installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, ansible

I have problem with the installation of ansible on my Xubuntu 18.04.

It complains:

```
sudo apt install ansible               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ansible : Depends: python-httplib2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've 3 python installed on my computer:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
There are 3 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python2.7   3         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7   3         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.6   2         manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/python3.7   1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

As you can see version 3.7 is in using. When I try to install `python-httplib2` specific, it complains:

```
sudo apt-get install python-httplib2 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-httplib2 : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                   Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That one is probably better suited for https://askubuntu.com - My quick $0.02 from exeperience: [installing with pip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-with-pip) is by far the most flexible option on all distributions.

Comment: [Masoud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3625186) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69431205) saying "I think this guide will help you. [https://crunchify.com/how-to-install-ansible-on-linux-ubuntu-os/](https://crunchify.com/how-to-install-ansible-on-linux-ubuntu-os/)"